# ENABLING windows 8 driver signature enforcement

Tags: drivers, windows-8.1

Is there a way to re-enable windows 8 driver signature enforcement after you have disabled it? I am working with a hardware company and need to test their signed driver works. We had to disable this when we tested their unsigned driver. When you go through advanced start I can only find the option to disable it.

Thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It gets enabled automatically on the next reboot. No need to re-enable it.
Disabling is not permanent.

Not directly from MS, but still valuable I think:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8ee77513-95ce-4f26-aa2e-e15615422a74/permanently-disable-driver-signature-enforcement-on-win-81-x64?forum=w8itprohardware

"Since a patch for Vista RTM, the option to PERMANENTLY disabled driver signature enforcement is removed. There are tools outside to workarond it [...]"

Comment: If your looking for something for wider deployment (assuming the signed driver works) you can look into setting up an Applocker Publisher or Hash policy to enforce/allow the use of the driver.

Comment: Are you sure about this? And is there anything written that would prove this? I have had to uninstall the unsigned driver and reinstall it many times and I have restarted multiple times. Once a driver is accepted can it just be reinstalled without disabling again? 

As much of a pain as it is I need to show a client it installing the signed driver. In the end it may be easier to reformat.

Comment: I don't have proof directly from TechNet/MS, but this here should be close enough: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/8ee77513-95ce-4f26-aa2e-e15615422a74/permanently-disable-driver-signature-enforcement-on-win-81-x64?forum=w8itprohardware